# @PostConstruct Singleton member field

Tags: spring, annotations, fortify

In the below scenario, there is a generic controller. I am doing @PostConstruct to instantiate IfCompleted class. But the IfCompleted object is created as class variable. So fortify is throwing singleton member field. What is the solution to avoid this?

```
GenericController.java

@Controller
public class GenericController{

@Autowired
public UserService service;

@Autowired
public webRoot webroot;

public IfCompleted ifCompleted;

@PostContstruct
public void show(){
   ifCompleted = new IfCompleted(webroot);
}

.....
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What the example in the question essentially does is take the control away from Spring, which is generally not a good thing. `IfCompleted` should be a bean whose lifecycle and wiring is controlled by Spring.

Assuming you can't or would prefer not to use XML or Java-based Container configuration to define the singleton `IfCompleted` with a `@DependsOn` constraint, it is now possible to create a bean definition from a `@Component` also, if for example you could only rely on component scanning.

Other useful tools for more complex lifecycle management are the `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` and `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware` interfaces.

The **short/quick** answer may be simply a case of defining the member as `static`, but I'm not familiar with Fortify's static analysis rules.

Comment: If the member is changed to static, it wont be thread safe.Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Explain how making it static doesn't make it thread safe, a `@Controller` in standard Spring MVC is a singleton anyway, your `@PostConstruct` runs once. Being static or not, your IfCompleted object could be accessed concurrently anyway. Your example is very generic, maybe we could give some better advice with more detail. Can you explain what IfCompleted does?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the advice. I solved it by removing @PostConstruct block, and @Autowired for WebRoot declaration.I injected WebRoot as constructor argument for IfCompleted in the spring context.

@Controller
public class GenericController{

@Autowired
public UserService service;

@Autowired
public IfCompleted ifCompleted;